# Java Pattern Matcher: create new or reset?

Tags: java, regex

Assume a regular expression, which, via a Java `Matcher` object, is matched against a large number of strings:

```
String expression = ...; // The Regular Expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
String[] ALL_INPUT = ...; // The large number of strings to be matched

Matcher matcher; // Declare but not initialize a Matcher

for (String input:ALL_INPUT)
{
    matcher = pattern.matcher(input); // Create a new Matcher

    if (matcher.matches()) // Or whatever other matcher check
    {
         // Whatever processing
    }
}
```

In the [Java SE 6 JavaDoc for Matcher](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/index.html?java/util/regex/Matcher.html), one finds the option of reusing the same `Matcher` object, via the `reset(CharSequence)` method, which, as the source code shows, is a bit less expensive than creating a new `Matcher` every time, i.e., unlike above, one could do:

```
String expression = ...; // The Regular Expression
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(expression);
String[] ALL_INPUT = ...; // The large number of strings to be matched

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(""); // Declare and initialize a matcher

for (String input:ALL_INPUT)
{
    matcher.reset(input); // Reuse the same matcher

    if (matcher.matches()) // Or whatever other matcher check
    {
         // Whatever processing
    }
}
```

Should one use the `reset(CharSequence)` pattern above, or should they prefer to initialize a new `Matcher` object every time?

Comment: By all means reuse the `Matcher`. The only good reason to create a new  `Matcher` is to ensure thread-safety. That's why you don't make a `public static Matcher m`---in fact, that's the reason a separate `Pattern` class exists in the first place.

Comment: So, for single-threaded applications even as an instance or class variable, or for multi-threaded ones in which the Matcher object is created inside a method, reset() is fine, yes?

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I think separating the compilation of the regex from it's application is another good reason for having a `Pattern` class.

Comment: In every situation where you are sure there's only one user of `Matcher` at any point in time, it is OK to reuse it with `reset`.

Comment: @JoachimSauer For that they could just have offered `public static Matcher compile(String regexp)`. It doesn't motivate a separate factory object.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Thanks for the clarification. I have numerous scenarios of Matcher objects created inside static methods and heavily used, so replacing re-instantiation with reset() will definitely improve application performance.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: I don't follow. Would that `Matcher` then be a `Matcher` with no `CharSequence` to match on? So you'd suddenly have two different "states" of `Matcher`: with or without a string to be matched-on.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I'm just writing a comment, not carefully designing the API as we speak. You must not imagine `Matcher` to be the one we are used to, but a blend of `Pattern` and `Matcher`. The API would just be different. For comparison you can see how they implemented XPath in jaxen.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik: ok, never mind my asking, I was just curious as how you'd have approached that.

Comment: @JoachimSauer I've thought about it for a minute, it probably would make sense to have that kind of `Matcher` start its life in the state of "no input". That wouldn't be a new state, though, because the real JDK `Matcher` finds itself in more-or-less the same state when it is done processing a string.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik Can you please create a new answer to the question and copy-paste (a summary of) your comments there, so that I accept it and other people can mark it? Thanks!

Comment: Just for information, both reset() method and reset(CharSequence) method were introduced in java.util.regex.Matcher class in Java 1.5 and are there since then.

Comment: In the "new Matcher" code, the premature declaration of the Matcher variable does not make any sense (it is not a C++ automatic variable), but the comment might look like it did to some readers.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

By all means reuse the `Matcher`. The only good reason to create a new `Matcher` is to ensure thread-safety. That's why you don't make a `public static Matcher m`—in fact, that's the reason a separate, thread-safe `Pattern` factory object exists in the first place.

In every situation where you are sure there's only one user of `Matcher` at any point in time, it is OK to reuse it with `reset`.

Comment: I think this answer would be better if it had an example showing use of `reset`...

Comment: I encourage you to improve this decade-old answer :)