# How can i match particular format in input using java.util.regex in java?

Tags: java, regex

### **INPUT**

Input can be in any of the form shown below with following mandatory content **TXT{`Any comma separated strings in any format`}**

```
String loginURL = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&password={PASS}";
String loginURL1 = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}";
String loginURL2 = "http://ip:port/path?TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}";
String loginURL3 = "http://ip:port/path?TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}";
String loginURL4 = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&password={PASS}";
```

### **Required Output**

**1. OutputURL corresponding to loginURL.**

```
String outputURL = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}";
String outputURL1 = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}";
String outputURL2 = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}";
String outputURL3 = "http://ip:port/path?";
String outputURL4 = "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&password={PASS}";
```

**2. Deleted pattern(if any)**

```
String deletedPatteren = TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
```

### **My Attempts**

```
String loginURLPattern = TXT+"\\{([\\w-,]*)\\}&*";

System.out.println("1. ");
getListOfTemplates(loginURL, loginURLPattern);
System.out.println();

System.out.println("2. ");
getListOfTemplates(loginURL1, loginURLPattern);
System.out.println();

private static void getListOfTemplates(String inputSequence,String pattern){
    System.out.println("Input URL : " + inputSequence);
    Matcher templateMatcher =  Pattern.compile(pattern).matcher(inputSequence);
    if (templateMatcher.find() && templateMatcher.group(1).length() > 0) {
        System.out.println(templateMatcher.group(1));
        System.out.println("OutputURL : " + templateMatcher.replaceAll(""));
    }
}
```

**OUTPUT obtained**

```
1. 
Input URL : http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&password={PASS}
UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&password={PASS
OutputURL : http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&

2. 
Input URL : http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password
OutputURL : http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}&
```

### **DRAWBACK OF ABOVE PATTERN**

If i add any String `containing character like #,%,@ in between TXT{}` then my code breaks.

How can i achieve it using java.util.regex library so that user can input any comma separated String between `TXT{Any Comma Separated Strings}`.

Comment: Wouldn't you be better off with a proper JSON parser?

Comment: You are misinterpreting it with word JSON, i have changed it to TXT.please see update

Comment: Do you really want to keep the `&` at the end of `outputURL1`?

Comment: @Keppil No there is nothing like that. will edit it...

Comment: Uhm, isn't that a URI template you are dealing with here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would recommend using `Matcher.appendReplacement`:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws Exception {
    final String[] loginURLs = {
        "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&password={PASS}",
        "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}",
        "http://ip:port/path?TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}",
        "http://ip:port/path?TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}",
        "http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&password={PASS}"};
    final Pattern patt = Pattern.compile("(\\?)?&?(TXT\\{[^}]++})(&)?");
    for (final String loginURL : loginURLs) {
        System.out.printf("%1$-10s %2$s%n", "Processing", loginURL);
        final StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        final Matcher matcher = patt.matcher(loginURL);
        while (matcher.find()) {
            final String found = matcher.group(2);
            System.out.printf("%1$-10s %2$s%n", "Found", found);
            if (matcher.group(1) != null && matcher.group(3) != null) {
                matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$1");                
            } else {
                matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$3");
            }
        }
        matcher.appendTail(sb);
        System.out.printf("%1$-10s %2$s%n%n", "Processed", sb.toString());
    }
}
```

Output:

```html
Processing http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&password={PASS}
Found      TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
Processed  http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}

Processing http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}&TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
Found      TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
Processed  http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}

Processing http://ip:port/path?TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}&username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}
Found      TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
Processed  http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}

Processing http://ip:port/path?TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
Found      TXT{UE-IP,UE-Username,UE-Password}
Processed  http://ip:port/path

Processing http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&password={PASS}
Processed  http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&password={PASS}
```

As you rightly point out, there are 3 possible cases:

1. "?{TEXT}&" -> "?"
2. "&{TEXT}&" -> "&"
3. "?{TEXT}" -> ""

So what we need to do is test for those cases in the regex. Here is the pattern:

```
(\\?)?&?(TXT\\{[^}]++})(&)?
```

Explanation:

- `(\\?)?` optionally matches and captures a `?`
- `&?` optionally captures an `&`
- `(TXT\\{[^}]++})` matches and captures `TXT`, followed by `{`, followed by one or most **not** `}` (possessively), followed by `}` (closing brackets don't need to be escaped
- `(&)?` optionally matches and captures a `&`

We have 3 groups:

1. potentially a `?`
2. the required text
3. potentially an `&`

Now when we find a match we need to replace with the appropriate capture of case `1..3`

```
if (matcher.group(1) != null && matcher.group(3) != null) {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$1");                
} else {
    matcher.appendReplacement(sb, "$3");
}
```

*If groups `1` and `3` are both present*:

We must be in case `1`; we must replace with "?" which is in group `1` so `$1`.

*Otherwise we are in case `2` or `3`*:

In case 2 we need to replace with "&" and in `3` with "".
In case `2` group `3` will hold "&" and in case `3` it will hold "" so we can replace with `$3` in both these cases.

Here I only capture the `TXT{...}` part using a match group. This means that although the leading `?` or `&` is replaced it is not in the `String found`. I you only want the bit between `{}` then just move the parenthesis.

Note that I reuse the `Pattern` - you can also [reuse the `Matcher`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391337/java-pattern-matcher-create-new-or-reset) if performance is a concern. You should always reuse the `Pattern` as it is (very) expensive to create. Store it in a `static final` if you can - it's threadsafe, matchers are not. The usual way to do it is to store the `Pattern` in a `static final` and then reuse the `Matcher` in the context of a method.

Also, the use of `Matcher.appendReplacement` is much more efficient than your current approach as it only needs to process the input once. Your approach parses the string twice.

Comment: I also required the replaced String.

Comment: It has not solved my problem, For third input, actual is *http://ip:port/path&username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}* and desired is *http://ip:port/path?username=abcd&location={LOCATION}&password={PASS}*

Comment: Please take your time, i will wait for your solution.

Comment: @Prateek [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557708/regex-possesive-quantifier/22558236#22558236) might be of interest - that's why it took quite so long to find the answer.