# how to replace multiple matched Regex

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a set of regex replacements that are needed to be applied to a set of  String,

For example:

1. all multiple spaces with single space `("\s{2,}" --> " ")`
2. all . followed by a char with . followed by space followed by the char  `(\.([a-zA-Z]-->". $1")`

So I will have something like this:

```
String s="hello     .how are you?";
s=s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}"," ");
s=s.replaceAll("\\.([a-zA-Z])",". $1");
....
```

it works , however imagine I'm trying to replace 100+ such expressions on a long String. needless to say how slow this can be.

so my question is if there is a  more efficient way to generalize these replacements with a single replaceAll (or something similar e.g. Pattern/Matcher)

I have followed [Java Replacing multiple different...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1326682/java-replacing-multiple-different-substring-in-a-string-at-once-or-in-the-most),

but the problem is that my regex(s) are not `simple Strings`.

Comment: You can use a single big regex and [`Matcher.appendReplacement`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#appendReplacement-java.lang.StringBuffer-java.lang.String-). You'll have to be very careful with your regex however - as it maybe get somewhat messy and possibly suffer from catastrophic backtracking.

Comment: @BoristheSpider if I use this then I have the  problem of knowing which regex is been used.

Comment: Nope, simply use capturing groups and check which one has data in it.

Comment: @BoristheSpider let's say I matched `.A` how would I know if this was matched using `\\.([a-zA-Z])`

Comment: If you have a pattern, for example `(A)|(B)` then you know, when you get a match, either group 1 or group 2 will be filled - the other will be empty (barring [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22557708/regex-possesive-quantifier)). You can use that to determine the replacement.

Comment: I feel this is turning int a `xy problem`

Comment: If any answer actually answers your question then you should accept it.

Answer (score 4):

You have these 2 `replaceAll` calls:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}"," ");
s = s.replaceAll("\\.([a-zA-Z])",". $1");
```

You can combine them into a single `replaceAll` like this:

```
s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}|(\\.)(?=[a-zA-Z])", "$1 ");
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aD5hM2/1)

Comment: This is a great observation mate, but unfortunately there are many other rules that can't fit into such a technique

Comment: I posted answer based on the code you have in question. If you show more code then I can better judge what can be done to optimize it.

Comment: thx mate, there are over 100 rules, obviously pointless to add them all, there is this one as well  `([a-zA-Z])\\-,([a-zA-Z])` --> `$1-$2`

Comment: @nafas This is a basis of a good solution, even if your expressions are "complex". If you can group all your regexes based on common replacement expressions, then chain calls to `replaceAll()` using regex alternation (as in this example), it will be as efficient as you can get it. eg `s = s.replaceAll("\\s{2,}|(\\.)(?=[a-zA-Z])", "$1 ").replaceAll("foo|bar|baz", "qux").replaceAll...;`

Comment: @Bohemian I agree, to be honest it took me by surprise when anubhava managed to combine them two. this way I can reduce the number of regexs i'm using but still have to have many repalceAll and etc..., I guess there is no hope for a single liner or anything more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [Replace multiple substrings at Once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7661460/replace-multiple-substrings-at-once) and modify it.

Use a `Map<Integer, Function<Matcher, String>>`.

- group numbers as Integer keys
- Lambdas as values

Modify the loop to check which group was matched. Then use that group number for getting the replacement lambda.

**Pseudo code**

```
Map<Integer, Function<Matcher, String>> replacements = new HashMap<>() {{
    put(1, matcher -> "");
    put(2, matcher -> " " + matcher.group(2));
}};

String input = "lorem substr1 ipsum substr2 dolor substr3 amet";

// create the pattern joining the keys with '|'. Need to add groups for referencing later
String regexp = "(\\s{2,})|(\\.(?:[a-zA-Z]))";

StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(regexp);
Matcher m = p.matcher(input);

while (m.find()) {
    //TODO change to find which groupNum matched
    m.appendReplacement(sb, replacements.get(m.group(groupNum)));
}
m.appendTail(sb);


System.out.println(sb.toString());   // lorem repl1 ipsum repl2 dolor repl3 amet
```