# Removing '|' , numbers and replacing with empty character in string -Java

Tags: java, string, replace

Example:

```
    String s1 = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("enter the string");
    String s2 = "h2ow |are you";
   
    
    if (s2.replace all("\\d+","").replaceAll("|", "").contains(s1))
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "true");
    
    else
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "false");
```

#### If I enter input as "how" the output is true

#### but, when I enter "how are" the output is false.

Is there a method to replace '|'(vertical bar)?

Answer (score 7):

You need to escape the pipe character (`|`). Unescaped, it is the [regular expression "or" operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22187948).

Try this:

```
s2.replaceAll("\\d|\\|", "").contains(s1)
```

This uses a literal pipe (regex=`\|`, escaped for Java=`"\\|"`) and an actual or-pipe (`|`). It says, replace any digit or literal pipe character with nothing.

Note, as stated by @alfasin, the function is named `replaceAll`, not `replace_all`.

Also, if this function is going to be used repeatedly in the same execution, then consider [reusing the matcher object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391337/java-pattern-matcher-create-new-or-reset), instead of using the string version (which creates a Matcher object each time).

---

Please consider bookmarking the Stack Overflow [Regular Expression FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075) for future reference.

Answer (score 2):

Additional to guys answer you can also use:

```
if (s2.replaceAll("[\\d\\|]","").contains(s1))
```

This regex is better on performance that doing `.replaceAll` twice or using `|` on regex (regex OR)

Answer (score 1):

`|` means or with regex so escape the `|` to match the actual character:

```
if (s2.replaceAll("\\d+","").replaceAll("\\|", "").contains(s1))
```