# Java regex, matches and find

Tags: java, regex

I am still having problems understanding difference in matches() and find(), here the code

```
final Matcher subMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("123");
System.out.println("Found : " + subMatcher.matches());
System.out.println("Found : " + subMatcher.find());
```

Output is

`Found : true 
 Found : false`

Of what I understand about matches and find from this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4450045/difference-between-matches-and-find-in-java-regex), is that matches() tries to match the whole string while find() only tries to match the next matching substring, and the matcher adds a ^ and $ meta-character to start and beginning and the find() can have different results if we use it multiple no of times, but here still 123 remains a substring, and the second output should be true. If i comment out the second line then it does shows output as true

Comment: You're using the same matcher twice. If you take out the `matches()` check, then the `find()` check will work.

Comment: try swapping `find` and `matches` and observe what happens ;)

Comment: @Blobonat I read that question and its mentioned in a link too in the question..

Comment: @Cloverr `matches()` matches the entire reagion, `find()` tries to matches the next region. when `matches()` is called the next region is already at the end of the String, so `find()` doesn´t have a region to match up against anymore. As a result you get `false`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you call `matches()`, the `Matcher` already searches for a match (the whole `String`). Calling `find` the `Matcher` will try to find the pattern again after the current match, but since there are no characters left after a match that matches the entire `String`, `find` returns `false`.

To search the`String` again, you'd need to create a new `Matcher` or call `reset()`:

```
final Matcher subMatcher = Pattern.compile("\\d+").matcher("123");
System.out.println("Found : " + subMatcher.matches());
subMatcher.reset();
System.out.println("Found : " + subMatcher.find());
```

Comment: from [this Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391337/java-pattern-matcher-create-new-or-reset) it should be better to reuse the matcher instead of creating a new one.

Comment: If I call matches() twice, the second one would start again from beginning or after where the previous matches() ended?

Comment: @Cloverr from the beginning. `matches` always checks from the start of the region, which is the whole string by default.