# create reusable Java Matcher

Tags: java, regex

I understand from [Java Pattern Matcher: create new or reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11391337/421049) that it's best to reuse a `Matcher` if I'm in a single-threaded context.

So let's say I have a stream of paths using `File.list(basePath)` and I want to filter them based upon matching their filenames against a regex. It seems I should use `matcher.reset(filename)` for each path filename in the stream. Wonderful.

But how do I initialize the `Matcher` so that I can reuse it, without first creating it and matching against something? Because I don't know what the first "something" will be—I won't even know if there will be a "something" (e.g. a file in some directory).

So do I do this to kick things off?

```
final Matcher filenamePatternMatcher=filenamePattern.matcher("");
```

That seems cumbersome and wasteful. But if I set `filenamePatternMatcher` to `null`, I'll have to do needless checks processing the individual files, like:

```
if((filenamePatternMatcher!=null
    ? filenamePatternMatcher.reset(filename)
    : filenamePattern.matcher(filename)).matches) {…}
```

Besides, I can't even do that within a `Stream<Path>`, because the matcher must be effectively final.

So what's an elegant way to create a matcher that will later match against strings using `Matcher.reset()`? Did the Java API creators not think of this use case?

Answer (score 0):

I did a few timings on some file name matching I do frequently, and calling `Matcher.reset(String)` improves the matching speed by ~20% / cuts down memory used.

Fortunately `Matcher.reset()` returns `this` to make it easy to reference within a  stream filter, and although it appears a little wasteful to setup a blank matcher before use, it is worth the effort to change from:

```
stream.filter(s -> pattern.matcher(s).matches())
```

... to have extra line to initialise the Matcher:

```
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("");
stream.filter(s -> matcher.reset(s).matches())
```