# Is java regex matcher stateful?

Tags: java, regex, stateful

I come from the python side and does not know much about java regex, the question is pretty self explanatory, let me add some scenario.

Assume I have an instance with a `Matcher matcher` variable, and a function like this:

```
public String getMatch(String group) {
    if (matcher.find()) {
        return matcher.group(group);
    } else { blah }
}
```

Where all regex capturing groups are named, Would calling it multiple time cause problems?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Yes `Matcher` is stateful.
2. If *anything*<sup>1</sup> calls `find` or `match` while you are (still) looking at the groups (etc) from the previous call, then you will lose the state from the previous call.   The same applies for `reset` and `reset(CharSequence)`, and some other methods.  This behavior is inherent in the API design, and clearly documented.
3. `Matcher` is not thread-safe.  The [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html) states this explicitly:

   > *"Instances of this class are not safe for use by multiple concurrent threads."*
4. However, using it like your code does should work ... *provided* that the `Matcher` was only visible to / used by the current thread, and not used further up (or down) the call stack.

See also:

- [Java Pattern Matcher: create new or reset?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11391337/java-pattern-matcher-create-new-or-reset) ... though the accepted answer is missing the "recursion" caveat.

---

By contrast, `Pattern` is both thread-safe and immutable / stateless.

---

<sup>1 - That could be another thread, or the current thread that is using the same `Matcher` at different points in the call stack; i.e. via recursion or something like that.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

`Pattern` is thread-safe, but `Matcher` is not.

`Matcher` maintains some local variables like `groupVars`, `localVars`, `last` etc.

`groupVars` is used for recording group captured, it will be reset before each `Matcher#match` and `Matcher#find` operation.

`localVars` is used for recording the context of matching operation.

`last` is used by `find`, it represents the terminal offset of previous `find` operation.

If you use `Matcher` concurrently, those local variables will be covered by different thread, which could cause unexpected result.